# Huge performance slowdown - vectors the problem?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

This part of my code is meant to take an irregularly-shaped outline of `Tile` objects and loop through creating a ring and decreasing the height value of the tiles in the ring while expanding the ring each time to include those tiles just outside the previous ring (does that make sense?).  What I find, however, is that I'm getting massive performance slowdowns, with each loop absurdly slower than the one before.  Why could this be?

I was thinking it might be because of the noobish `oldEdge = theEdge;` and comparable lines (both are vectors, I'm assigning one to the other).  But even so, I don't understand the huge performance drop.  Maybe I'm doing something obviously silly.  Can someone set me straight?

Note that `oldEdge`, `theEdge` and `newEdge` are all `vector<Tile*>`s.

```
int decrease = 1;
while(decrease < 10)
{
    cout << "Trying to smooth!\n";
    //First, modify the new edge.
    int newHeight = 70 - decrease;
    cout << "Height at: " << newHeight << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < newEdge.size(); ++i)
    {
        newEdge[i]->SetHeight(newHeight);
    }
    //Increment decrease.
    decrease += 1;
    //Set the oldEdge and theEdge variables.
    oldEdge = theEdge;
    theEdge = newEdge;
    newEdge.clear();
    //Finally, find the new edge.
    cout << "Finding new edge!\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < theEdge.size(); ++i)
    {
        //cout << "Checking a tile's neighbors!\n";
        for(int j = 0; j < theEdge[i]->m_AdjacentTiles.size(); ++j)
        {
            bool valid = true;
            //Is this neighbor in theEdge?
            //cout << "Is this neighbor in theEdge?\n";
            for(int k = 0; k < theEdge.size(); ++k)
            {
                if(theEdge[i]->m_AdjacentTiles[j] == theEdge[k])
                {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //If not, is it in oldEdge?
            if(valid)
            {
                //cout << "Is this neighbor in oldEdge?\n";
                for(int k = 0; k < oldEdge.size(); ++k)
                {
                    if(theEdge[i]->m_AdjacentTiles[j] == oldEdge[k])
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //If neither, it must be valid for continued expansion.
            if(valid)
            {
                newEdge.push_back(theEdge[i]->m_AdjacentTiles[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `Tile*` instead of `Tile`? And have you tried changing the assignments for a `swap`s, since you discard the `newEdge` anyway?

Comment: You've got a 3-nested loop. First look inside the innermost loop. Example: `theEdge[i]->m_AdjacentTiles[j]` can be moved out of the loop. (Don't count on the compiler to do it.) Also, I would count down, as in `for(int k = theEdge.size(); valid && --k >= 0;)`.

Comment: Can you give a rough idea of the kind of `size()` numbers you're dealing with? Not that it necessarily affects the logic, but it could help direct where to optimize.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code yet?

Comment: You write of "performance slowdown" and "performance drop", but I can't find where you came from and what you changed that made the performance drop.

Comment: @sbi: He clarifies in his description that the "slowdown" is relative to each iteration within the loop. I'm assuming he means the outer `while` loop; each iteration is drastically slower than the one before.

Comment: Yes, each iteration is drastically slower.  The first two or three are acceptable, but after that it gets unbearable, and I've seen the last loop run for over 3 minutes without a change.  `size()` values range from roughly 800-3000.  I'll take a look at people's suggestions so far, and post what happened!  Thanks!

Comment: @dolphy: Ah, I don't know why I didn't see that...

Comment: I don"t know if this is the answer but if you measure speed for std containers (std::map, std::vector etc.) the readings will be off track if you do it in debug mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm, as best I can tell, is `O(n^2 * m)` in the number of edges and adjacent tiles. Most likely just a small increase causes the asymptotic performance to blow up and you see the slowdown. If the edge containers were sorted you could use a binary search instead, or if you were able to hash them instead that would also be an option.

I'm not familiar enough with the algorithm you're trying to use but you might want to revisit if there's a fundamentally different approach you should use.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the vector, it's the algorithm.

You have a three-times nested loop in there. Put some debug statements in to find out how many times it goes through each loop.